# Use cons in front of arguments in racket/scheme

Tags: scheme, racket, cons

I know `cons` is for building pairs, like `(cons 2 (cons 3 empty))`, but I don't understand the code here that use `cons` after `empty`. Isn't `cons` built for numbers? How can `cons` take 2 arguments? If they can take 2 arguments, how does it evaluate them? and can someone please translate the code after `[(empty? lst) empty]` please.

```
(define (removed2 lst)
  (cond
       [(empty? lst) empty]
       [(not (member? (first lst) (rest lst)))
        (cons (first lst) (removed2 (rest lst)))]
       [else (removed2 (rest lst))])
```

Comment: Have a look at https://www.shido.info/lisp/scheme3_e.html

Comment: You should spend some time reading the [documentation](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html) and a good [book](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-15.html#%_sec_2.2), I'm certain that your text book includes explanations to all your questions.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you *read* a good book or a tutorial on Scheme, you're asking for explanations of some of the most basic concepts, that should be well-understood before starting to code in Scheme. For instance, this [chapter](http://www.htdp.org/2003-09-26/Book/curriculum-Z-H-13.html#node_chap_9) is a great starting point. I'll address your questions:

> I know `cons` is for building pairs, like `(cons 2 (cons 3 empty))`

Indeed, you can build pairs of *anything* you want… pairs of numbers, pairs of pairs, you name it.

> But I don't understand the code here that use `cons` after `empty`.

In this case, `empty` means the empty list `'()`. So, we can build a pair where the first element is an atom (a number in this case) and the second is an empty list - and that's how we build proper lists in Scheme!

> Isn't `cons` built for numbers?

No, it's for building pairs of *anything*, including other pairs.

> How can `cons` take 2 arguments? If they can take 2 arguments, how does it evaluate them?

And why not? as you've already stated, `cons` is for building *pairs*. A pair is made up of two things, so `cons` takes 2 arguments. It evaluates each of them in turn and then sticks them together to form a pair. You should really, really read the [documentation](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._cons%29%29).

> And can someone please translate the code after `[(empty? lst) empty]` please

That's just asking if the list we're recursively traversing is empty, if it is, then it returns an empty list - the base case of any recursive procedure that returns a list. The procedure is simply building a list as a result, for that is `cons`ing elements to pairs, and the last pair ends with an empty list, producing a proper list. Basically, this is how you build a list in Scheme:

```
(cons 1 (cons 2 (cons 3 empty)))
=> '(1 2 3)
```